# Cannot compile C++ files on Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 (version.h error)

Tags: 14.04, server, g++

I have tried using make and G++ to compile C++ files on my Ubuntu VPC... when I attempt to compile it leads with the  following error:

```
Daemon.cpp:5:21: fatal error: version.h: No such file or directory
 #include "version.h"
```

From what I understand the version of g++ i'm using is not matching the kernal of ubuntu I have; I attempted to run g++-4.8 but that leads to the same error.

Comment: `#include "version.h"` (as opposed to `#include <version.h>`) would usually refer to a local, non-system header file. What software are you trying to build, exactly? How did you arrive at the conclusion that it's related to a kernel mismatch?

Comment: I am building a CryptoNote currency and I am trying to compile and run the Daemon.cpp to get start the genesis block.

Comment: Can you please link to the exact code (github repo?) that you are using - there seem to be several candidates

Comment: https://github.com/cryptonotefoundation/cryptonote Of course I am changing parts of the code to suit my needs but its almost the same. File I'm compiling js within /cryptonote/src/daemon/daemon.cpp

Comment: So please [edit] your question to show exactly how you are configuring and trying to build the project: it is probably referring to the `version/version.h` file that should have been created from `src/version.h.in` file by the `cmake` process

Comment: Sorry, What exactly do you mean by that? I have very little server knowledge and command line knowledge of Linux OS's but I am learning. I am probably making a basic error.

Comment: Well, did you follow the instructions ("**First step**" to "**Sixth step**") on the github page (or - equivalently -  in the `README.md` file)?

Comment: I have made it to the Sixth step, but it simply states to "Run your daemon with --print-genesis-tx argument" That is where I am stuck on. I assume running the daemon means compiling and running it.

Comment: OK - but *how* are you trying to compile it? it should be sufficient to run `make` from the top level directory. As part of that step, the `./build/release/version/version.h` file should be created.

Comment: I am trying to compile it using g++, make says there is nothing to compile. If you'd like to take a swing at it yourself you can PM me.

Comment: You need to run `make` from the top-level `cryptonote` directory (the directory that contains README.md and CMakeLists.txt files etc.)

Comment: When doing so g++ says there is no such file or directory. I must be pointing to the wrong location. Make doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel header package seem to be (broken?) missing in your system.
If you could install it by `apt`,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Restart your system for the change to take effect.

Comment: It's almost always better to install the `linux-headers-generic` dependency package (so that the headers are updated automatically along with the kernel)

Comment: @steeldriver Ah, I agree. Edited to include this.

Comment: I have already done that... But I reinstalled and restarted. I removed all versions of g++ and then reinstalled, confirming I am using version 4.8.5. It still leads to the same error.

Comment: @iw0542 Could you please do a `find / -name "version.h" -type f` and provide us the output? Also tell us which package you are trying to compile.

Comment: find "version.h" -type f
find: `version.h': No such file or directory

Comment: I cannot see if you did a whole system search. Are you sure you did not omit `/` in `find`? Provide the details of package you are trying to install.